# normalizing difference of 2 numbers

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

I'm making a simple graph drawing shader, but have encounted a problem with making the lines of equal thickness everywhere.

When I dont normalize it it turns out a bit thicker in areas where the diffrence is smaller. When I normalize it it turns out very disturted.

```
#version 460 core

layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;

in vec4 gl_FragCoord;

uniform vec2 Screen_Size;
uniform vec2 zoom;
uniform vec2 offset;
#define GRAPHCOLOR vec3(0.176, 0.439, 0.701)

float leftside(vec2 pos) {
    return(pos.y);
}
float rightside(vec2 pos) {
    return(pos.x);
}
vec2 cameramat(vec2 pos) {
    return((pos - offset) * zoom);
}
void main() {
    float eps = (50.0*sqrt(zoom.x*zoom.y)) / 2000.0;
    vec2 pos = cameramat(2.0 * (gl_FragCoord.xy / Screen_Size) - vec2(1, 1));
    vec3 _color = vec3(0.9, 0.9, 0.9);
    vec2 sides = (vec2(leftside(pos), rightside(pos)));

    _color = mix(_color, vec3(0.70), step(abs(pos.x - float(int(pos.x))), 0.002 * zoom.x));
    _color = mix(_color, vec3(0.70), step(abs(pos.y - float(int(pos.y))), 0.002 * zoom.y));

    _color = mix(_color, vec3(0.4), step(abs(pos.x), 0.002 * zoom.x));
    _color = mix(_color, vec3(0.4), step(abs(pos.y), 0.0025 * zoom.y));

    _color = mix(_color, mix(_color, GRAPHCOLOR, step(abs((sides.x - sides.y)), eps / 2)),smoothstep(eps, 0, abs((sides.x - sides.y))));

    color = vec4(_color, 0.9);
}
```

Here are a few example graphs:

| non normalized x = y | non normalized 50x = 50y | non normalized x = y | normalized 50x = 50y |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UKsI.png] | [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFM9i.png] | [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqkLe.png] | [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyXyt.png] |

Here is the full project:

- https://github.com/urisinger/graphcalc

Comment: you've put "non normalized" two times in your table for the x = y case.

Comment: no the graph is the same

Answer (score 0):

so apparently i had to multiply eps by the magnitude of the gradiant, ill leave this open incase someone encounters a simular problem